# Inferring BUFGMUX in Xilinx FPGAs for Clock Multiplexing

Tags: verilog, vhdl, clock, xilinx

I have a VHDL memory core which requires me to multiplex between two clocks. The Write clock operates at 200 Mhz and Read clock operates at 100 Mhz. I think this can be done using `BUFGMUX` (correct me if there is a better way to do this)

Is it possible to somehow infer this in VHDL instead of instantiating it ? What are your experiences with this ? Can you post some sample code ?

*** EDIT ***

The READ ports are completely occupied and need to be used simultaneously. The write operation will occur only once in the start as an initialization step.

RRS

Comment: The dual-port memories can use separate clocks for writing and reading to begin with. You don't need to multiplex anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have EDITED the question. I need one write port and 2 read ports on the RAM. The write will not occur during the READs. WRITE occurs as part of an initialization step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than multiplex a clock (or divide it) use one clock for both read ports and use two separate (or multiplexed) enable lines (i.e. the port read enables) to do the reading. This is better than adding any logic/delay to the clock line.

Comment: Do you suggest doing the WRITE at the same clock as the READ ?

Comment: No, you said you wanted to use both READ ports at the same time. I'm suggesting you use the enable lines to manipulate the reads as desired. For instance if you want to read at half speed, then divide the clock by 2 and use that to drive the RAMs enable line (as opposed to using the divided clock on the RAMs clock line)

Answer (score 3):

I've not successfully inferred a BUFGMUX.

I'm a big fan of inference, but for dealing with clock components, I instantiate them.  There's not usually too many instantiations to be done and they can be contained to the top level so portability isn't hurt too much.